Missing Transaction from Node Contract!
I need help!
I have applied for my reward in node contract platformer but the funds didn't come to my Coinbase Wallet and there is no Transaction Hash in Etherscan.
The comment from platform is below:
Dear user: Regarding your situation, our technical team has inspected and concluded that your funds are blocked in the withdrawal channel, resulting in the funds being unable to reach your wallet.
Solution: You need to reverse transfer 10% of the withdrawn funds to the platform receiving address to export the blocked coins.
How to proceed in this case?

It’s totally a SCAM. Don’t fall for it and transfer anything or share any personal details. Be safe!

Thanks for the answer. What do you suggest now?

I mean, you have't lost anything. Right? If it's just for winning some reward, then you can just avoid it, as it totally seems to be a trap.

They have my funds on their platform. Can you please tell me what would be the right procedure in this case?

Sorry to say, but I don’t think that whatever funds you’ve deposited are recoverable. That’s why, I advised you to not transfer any more funds that they’re asking for. As, they usually keep asking for more, to recover the previous, that they never do.

Thanks for the advice!

Is there a legal procedure to sue them?
